# Add an SPGroup to another SPGroup

Tags: groups, inheritance

Is there a way to add a SharePoint group to another SharePoint group? This would work like Active Directory.

IE. I want to put the two child groups into the parent group instead of adding all of the users again to the parent group.

HR Employees (parent group)

HR Managers (child group)

HR Non-Managers (child group)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you cannot add one SharePoint group into another Sharepoint group.  You'll need to use AD security groups within the SharePoint groups to achieve that affect if you don't want to manually add members.

Comment: There's one point missing in Eric's answer. While SharePoint groups may not be included in other SharePoint groups, a SharePoint group can **own** another SharePoint group (or itself), view the owned group's role assignments (View group permissions) and manage the membership.

Comment: I didn't include it because it has no bearing on the answer.

Answer (score -4):

You can create a new sharepoint group and existing groups to it.

Create new SP Group HRParent and add HR Managers, HR Non Mangers (sharepoint group)

Comment: You cannot add SP groups to SP groups.